# Checking whether or not a variable has impact

Tags: regression, self-study, logistic, causality, confounding

For a statistics assignment, I've been given a data set (regarding drug prevention) and a few questions. One of the questions is to check whether or not the choice of treatment, treatment A or treatment B, impacts the odds of staying drug-free. We're told to be cautious about possible confounds, like a having history of intravenous drugs use.

Now, my problem is, I'm not really sure how to check if this has an impact or not, and even less sure how to keep the confounds in mind.

The given variables in the dataset are: Age, beck depression score, history of IV drug use (never, in the past or recently), number of previous treatments, race, duration of treatment (long/short), which treatment (A/B), and whether or not they were still drug-free after 12 months.

Comment: This question suggests logistic regression. To be cautious of confounders, you could include not only the treatment but also history of drug abuse as predictor.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the major subjects of Pearl's work, and is why it is standard in the field of epidemiology.  His approach is to build a causal model with links indicating all considered causal relationships.

Then, to evaluate your question: whether treatment has an effect on staying drug free, one wants to basically find out whether evidence flows along the edge from the node for treatment to the node for staying drug free.  There are two ways to do this:  The front door method and the back door method.

This is a nice presentation in his book:

J. Pearl, Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference. Cambridge University Press, 2000.

A more general version is provided by

J. Tian and J. Pearl, “A General Identification Condition for Causal Effects,” in AAAI/IAAI, 2002, pp. 567–573.

Answer (score 0):

Yes logistic regression or a loglinear model seem to be the approaches to take to this problem.  The binary outcome is whether or not the respondent stayed drug free.  All the variables that are potential confounders should be included in the model and you should also look at the interaction terms between the confounders and the treatments.  If the treatment effect remains significant when including all these other variables then it would be safe to conclude that there is a real treaatment effect.

Comment: This is a good way to check for associational dependencies, but not causal ones, which I think is what the question is asking.  One has to make sure that the treatment is not, for example, preferentially done to people who are drug free, and that there is no common cause between the treatment and staying drug free.

Comment: @NeilG  The OP asked to show whether or not treatment impacts the whether or not the respondent remains drug free. This sounds to me like association or correlation.  While casuation is a possibility and it would be helpful to say that the introduction of a treatment caused an improvement in the proportion of respondents that remained drug-free it is not necessary to show that.

Comment: You're right that there's a question of interpretation here.  However, I don't think that an associational relationship is interesting with respect to treatment at all.  One is almost always interested in the causal relationship.  Personally, I think the word "impact" in the question indicates a desire for a causal relationship; if you believe otherwise, why would you use the word "effect" in your answer?  It is not safe to conclude any effect from the setup in your answer…

Comment: Sorry if I came off as harsh, but if you look at Pearl's smoking/cancer example, one could imagine doing a logistic regression model and uselessly concluding that smoking and cancer are correlated.  The whole point is to check whether smoking causes cancer.

Comment: The causality of smoking with cancer was a hotly fought issue in the statistical community where fisher played devils advocate and suggested several alternative links between smoking and cancer.  As for an example one could suppose that a person could have both a genetic propensity to want to smoke and also have a genetic link to ling cancer.  Causality is much harder to "prove" than association.  The word effect and impact do not necessarily mean cause.  While a model that associates smoking with cancer might seem to you to be useless i think that it is very useful in itself.

Comment: After all I don't think you would claim A causes B if they were statistically uncorrelated.

Comment: The reason that such associational models are probably "useless" is because they tell us: given a person who has already had treatment A (vs B), will that person stay drug free?  What we really want to know is: if a person having had no treatment yet, is made to take treatment A (vs B), will that person stay drug free?  In other words, we want $P(Y \mid \textrm{do}(x))$ rather than $P(Y \mid x)$.

Comment: I am having a hard time seeing the distinction you are trying to make.  Even if I were to accept your premise that it addresses a different question, I still don't see why that makes the result useless.

Comment: If you have access to the book I linked, I suggest you read the first two chapters.  I think you might find them as fascinating as I do.  It's hard for me to do as good a job as Pearl.  Nevertheless, the reason the associational model is useless is because we want to know whether the treatment is effective.  The fact of people accepting treatment A and staying drug free might indicate that the reason these people accepted treatment A in the first place is the true reason they are staying drug free, and so treatment A itself is irrelevant.

Comment: I have Pearl's book.

Comment: Great!  Kindly have a look at the epilogue, page 353 for me, where he writes "Consider the century-old debate concerning the effect of smoking on lung cancer…"  The next five pages are beautiful exposition of his ideas.